# How can i increase the data rate of ibmiot input node?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

I am sending data from my sensortag 2650 to the Node-RED platform through my smartphone. I am sending at the speed of 10 Hz. But the node is spitting out data at 1 Hz. How can I increase the data rate of the Node ibmiot?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read the following education about asking good questions, it includes on what to include to help people help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

**ibmiot** node does not play any role in setting the frequency of message rate. Thats done by the node which is sending the events to ibmiot node. So you need to change that part of the flow.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I am using Sensortag CC2650, a product of Texas Instrument. The sesnor can produce data at 10 Hz.  I am using Ibm quickstart which is sending the events to the node. When I am pushing the data to the cloud, I am getting data at 1 Hz rate. Can you suggest me anything?

Comment: Zishan, as I said earlier, iotnode does not perform any throttling. The issue could be at the previous nodes. You can try two things - 1) Add a debug node just before the iotnode to determine how frequent you are forwarding the events to iotnode. 2) Provide the Node-RED flow so that I can try it at my end.